# How do I crop the contents of an Iframe to show a part of a page?

Tags: asp.net, html, iframe

I am currently working on a website which must download content from another website through the use of an iframe. Is there any way that I can crop the contents of the downloaded page to only show a section of that page on my website?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can crop the contents of the downloaded page to only show a section of that page on my website?

No. The Same Origin Policy prevents you from manipulating the `iframe` in any way, including the scroll position.

There would be a workaround by putting the `iframe` into an  a `div` container that has a defined height and width, and `overflow: hidden` to clip the view port:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden">
```

and giving the `iframe` a relative position:

```
<iframe src="..." style="position: relative; left: -100px; top: -100px">
```

this way, you can adjust the portion of the iframe that is visible on the page. However, the whole page still gets rendered, and this approach is not immune to influences like scrolling inside the iframe.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: solid 2px #555; width:594px; height:332px;">
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -25px;">
</div>
<iframe src="http://www.centricle.com/tools/html-entities/" scrolling="no" style="height: 490px; border: 0px none; width: 619px; margin-top: -60px; margin-left: -24px; ">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

This code worked for me.

Source [ http://extechbuzz.blogspot.com/2012/12/iframe-how-to-display-specific-part-of.html ]

Comment: There is an extra <div> on third line.

Answer (score 5):

To crop off the ads at the bottom of the embedded [page](https://openflights.org/user/dankohn1), I used the following:

```
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 390px; overflow: hidden">
<iframe src="https://openflights.org/user/dankohn1" width="1000"
height="600" style="border:none" scrolling="no">
</iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In iframe you cant do it...but if you use HTTPWebRequest/WebResponse then its very simple...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

This pack is very important...you can read specific div /span by id ...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me... Adjust the margin-top and margin-left to whatever value suits you best and adjust height and width of iframe to whatever value you want.

```
<html>
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: -1440px; margin-left:0;">
<iframe src="https://fiitjeelogin.com/StartPage.aspx" scrolling="no" height="1550"width="300" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to prevent the page from scrolling.
Just add: scrolling="no"

```
<div class="form-computer">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf_rtGkQkzqHEw1IBk53QDITiSWDYW5RJQKDUvojAGN5dIXsg/viewform?embedded=true"
        width="100%" height="1915px" style="position: relative; top: -135px"
        frameborder="0"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        scrolling="no"
        >Social Media Use
    </iframe>
  </div>
```