# open only a specific div of a side in my browser

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

i have a rather strange question:
Is there a possibility to open a only a specific div element of a website in my browser?

The reason why i want to know is, because i want to embed only the stream element of this website:
http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2196420951001

The page is rather new, so they dont offer a share embed code function yet, therfore i thought about creating an Iframe which shows the stream, like this:

```
<iframe height="433" width="770" frameborder="0" src="http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2196420951001"></iframe>
```

While this iframe shows the whole site, i want only to show the stream element. I checked the code of the side and the div element called "player-wrap" shows pretty much what i need.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option may be to contact them and request embed functionality. It's maybe not their top priority so if you must, a possible workaround could be this ([modified from the SO post found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676721/1265817)).

```
div{
    width: 960px;
    height: 424px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
iframe{
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
}


<div>
    <iframe src="http://www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2196420951001" autoscroll="false"></iframe>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/5PMyu/

Comment: thanx this is awesome!!
I already contacted them, and they are working on embed and API but not finshed yet

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do it is to use jQuery's load function to return the iframe.

For example your code would be this which would return the wrapping div of the video which is called .palyer_wrap and insert it into #target-div.

```
$('#target-div').load('www.azubu.tv/channel/live_small.do?cn_id=2196420951001 .palyer_wrap');
```

Comment: I'm afraid this wont work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237707/load-website-into-div