# Google docs iframe size manipulation

Tags: html, google-docs

can I crop the contents of a google docs document to a4 size?

Thanks in advance everyone.

At the origin codes I've used

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQrIgSdrJ8nhsYmHVfHMU5X5KPDvXpGI5
    E2UGCGWYYciHCJd8edsj5UGZngkIbhjt1MJnBwzhuvxE_E/pub?embedded=true"
    name="myiFrame" style="clip: rect(10px, 10px, 10px, 10px); left: 20x;" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="px" marginwidth="0px" height="800px" 
    width="620px" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
    
    
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
       
    </style>
```

Comment: Do you want the iframe to display only the clipped part? Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5676721/4243927) answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

A4 is 3508 x 2480 px.
But I don't recommend setting it that big. You can keep the ratio, but make it smaller.
Anyways, the size you put is the best. Better don't change it.

See you later!