# How would I crop a HTML IFrame?

Tags: html, replit

How would I crop a HTML IFrame?
This is my code:
`<iframe style="margin: -10px; position: fixed;" src="https://replit.com/@Dragonterror/Google-Chrome?embed=true" width=100% height=100% margin=0></iframe>`
This is the [Result](https://h.dragonterror.repl.co)
I am tryin to crop off The Open In Replit bar, but KEEP the run and like bar. I've seen how to crop off the bottom, but not the top. Thanks!

I have tried overflow: Hidden, and many other things. But it only ever crops the bottom. Other questions were no help either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676672/how-do-i-crop-the-contents-of-an-iframe-to-show-a-part-of-a-page ☝ will this work?

Comment: No, that only crops the bottom.