# Embed p5.js sketch without logo and title

Tags: iframe, embed, p5.js

Does anyone know if it's possible to embed a p5.js sketch (iFrame) but without the title bar that is included when you copy the iframe code from editor.p5js.org?

```
<iframe src="https://editor.p5js.org/marteteigen/full/mm36uPgqW"></iframe>
```

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r1Pl.png)

Unfortunately I can't implement the js-file on the website here. I have to use iframe.

Answer (score 0):

to customize it you should implement the js-file.
Do you need help with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to remove the title bar. However, you can try hiding it by putting the whole `iframe` into a `div`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676672/how-do-i-crop-the-contents-of-an-iframe-to-show-a-part-of-a-page).